# Issue related to Jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have following Jquery

```
   $('#txtSearch_text').attrchange(function (attrName) {
                    if (counter > 0) {
                        var contains = $('#txtSearch_text').attr('class').indexOf("validation");

                        if ($('#txtSearch_text').val() == '' && contains <= -1) {
                            $('#txtSearch_text').addClass('validation');
                        }
                        else if ($('#txtSearch_text').val() != '' && contains >= 0) {
                            $('#txtSearch_text').removeClass('validation');

                        }
                    }

                    //counter = 1;

                });
```

The above jquery fires when `txtSearch` textbox changes any attribute. It works ok. but i want to fire above Jquery for multiple TextBoxes.. so if i have 4 TextBox then i will have to write Jquery 4 times for 4 different TextBox.

is there any way to write above jquery only one time for all TextBox ??

Thanks

Comment: use class instead of id, or use `,` sepearated id in function

Comment: use `class` , and make use of `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass comma seprated selector for all four textboxes. and inside use `$(this)` to get current object reference.Like this :

```
$('#txtSearch_text,#txtSearch_second,#txtSearch_third,#txtSearch_fourth').attrchange(function (attrName) {
  if (counter > 0) {
        var contains = $(this).attr('class').indexOf("validation");
  if ($(this).val() == '' && contains <= -1) {
  $(this).addClass('validation');
  }
  else if ($(this).val() != '' && contains >= 0) {
  $(this).removeClass('validation');
  }}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class like `txtSearch_text` to all 4 elements then use it as a selector to target them

```
$('.txtSearch_text').attrchange(function (attrName) {
    if (counter > 0) {
        var contains = $(this).attr('class').indexOf("validation");

        if ($(this).val() == '' && contains <= -1) {
            $(this).addClass('validation');
        } else if ($(this).val() != '' && contains >= 0) {
            $(this).removeClass('validation');

        }
    }

    //counter = 1;

});
```